# SSL configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I am trying to setup the ssl_requirement plugin.  For my users controller I would like to require ssl for new and create.  When I open users/new the browser redirects to https but I get an unable to connect error message.  The application error log says :

Filter chain halted as [:ensure_proper_protocol] rendered_or_redirected.

I am not sure if I have configured the plugin incorrectly or if I made an error with the nginx configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `form_for` uses a secure url:

```
form_for @user, :url => user_path(:secure => true)
```

Comment: I didn't realize this was needed; don't recall seeing it in the plugin readme.

Comment: It probably doesn't say this in the documentation and the reason isn't exactly clear, but the main gist of it is this: Assume you have a page that **only** accepts posts over https (using `ssl_requirement`).  If you `post` to that form over http, it will redirect and re-post over https; however, the initial damage is done as the data was sent at least **once** over http.  Basically -- be careful how you use this and make sure you're not entirely relying on the gem.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like what you *should* be seeing.  The request was recognized as an **http** request and was *redirected* to be served over **https**.

If you're on your development machine, it's going to redirect you to https://localhost/rest_of_url, so if you don't have a server running on your machine on port 443, then it's going to throw an error.

Is your browser not getting redirected?

Comment: I am trying to work this out on a production server actually.  The page does redirect from http to https for users/new but the browser says unable to connect.

Comment: How can i test nginx port 443 to see if the ssl setup is corrent?

Comment: I believe you'll have to specify a `server` in your nginx config file that listens to port 443.  This site has an example configuration with an app running on 443: http://articles.slicehost.com/2007/12/19/ubuntu-gutsy-nginx-ssl-and-vhosts

Comment: It looks like a nginx configuration issue.  I am unable to start nginx and I get this error:  Starting nginx: [emerg]: unknown directive "ssl" in /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:123.  That line is :
 ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/localcerts/domain_combined.crt;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when I installed nginx through passenger I did not get the ssl module.  I went back and installed nginx from source on it own.